# Test class for http callout on documents

Tags: apex, unit-test, httprequest, csv

I have a class that makes a HTTP callout and gets the csv response and save it to the content in salesforce.

**Apex class:**

```
public class MYSQLCSV{
    public Static void MySQLCSVContent(){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        string firstImageURL = 'http://domain.com/buyout/181';
        req.setEndpoint(firstImageURL);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        req.setCompressed(true);
        req.setTimeout(60000);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        res = h.send(req);
        string responseValue = '';
        responseValue = res.getBody();
        system.debug('Response Body for File: ' + responseValue);
        // getBodyAsBlob method 
        blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.VersionData = image;  //This is our blob
        cv.title = 'MyImageName';
        cv.Description = 'MyImageDescription';
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = '058r00111104L7I';  //This is the library
        cv.TagCsv = 'Tag1';
        cv.PathOnClient = 'http://domain.com/buyout/181';
        cv.ReasonForChange = ''; 
        //cv.ContentDocumentID = ''; 
        insert cv;
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
 @isTest
 global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
     global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
         System.assertEquals('http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar', req.getEndpoint());
         System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
         // Create a fake response
         HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
         res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');
         res.setStatusCode(200);
         return res;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on how to create the fake response for csv on the system.assert and also the code coverage for the Blob method.

Comment: Harish -- 1) did you look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm ; 2) res.setBody() just needs to generate a string as it is a mocked result that you eventually save in ContentVersion.  That is, it doesn't have to generate a legit csv string as your code doesn't care about parsing a CSV, just saving the file

Comment: @crop1645-I tried the test class above but I don't get any code coverage at all.

Comment: well - your test class as posted doesn't invoke `MYSQLCSV.MySQLCSVContent()` - you need to look at the example link I posted more carefully. All you've done is provide a mockresults implementation that SFDC will call when the http callout is attempted by sfdc in a test context